# Oracle SQL trigger - DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, dbms-output

I'm creating a trigger within my database, I came across two error that I am not able to fix, I'm pretty sure that those two are relating to my use of **DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE**, the rest of the statement does not cause any errors, although it had before.

Errors:

> Error(5,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> Error(5,15): PL/SQL: ORA-00903: invalid table name

Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER INVOICES
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON BRUINVOICE
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
  IF :new.BRU_DATE < :new.BRU_PAID_DATE THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You cannot do that');
  ELSE
  INSERT INTO table BRUINVOICE
  values 
  from inserted;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Your `INSERT` doesn't make sense.  There is no `table` keyword in an `INSERT` statement, it seems unlikely that you've created a table named `inserted` to select from and if you are intending to select from another table, you'd need an `INSERT ... SELECT`.  But since you're apparently inserting into the same table that your trigger is defined on, I'm hard-pressed to imagine what you are trying to accomplish.  Maybe you want to raise an error rather than writing to `dbms_output` and remove the `ELSE` clause entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check constraints are a better choice (performance-wise) than triggers when it comes to record level validation:

```
ALTER TABLE bruinvoice
ADD CONSTRAINT validate_bru_date CHECK (BRU_DATE < BRU_PAID_DATE);
```

Inserting invalid data will raise an error message like the following:

```
scott@ORCL> insert into bruinvoice values ('21-DEC-14','20-DEC-14');
insert into bruinvoice values ('21-DEC-14','20-DEC-14')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.VALIDATE_BRU_DATE) violated
```

Answer (score 3):

I fully agree with cstotzer, a check constraint is much better in your situation at should be the preferred way of doing it. However, **just for information** this would be the trigger syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER INVOICES
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON BRUINVOICE
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
  IF :new.BRU_DATE < :new.BRU_PAID_DATE THEN
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'You cannot do that');
  END IF;
END;
```

You don't need any `ELSE`, your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` will be simply executed in this case.